# How to get bluetooth connection status with Xamarin Essentials

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.essentials

I am trying to use the Xamarin Essentials Connectivity class in a Xamarin.Forms project to check if bluetooth is available:

```
var networkProfiles = Connectivity.Profiles;
if (!networkProfiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.Bluetooth))
{
   //Do Stuff
}
```

However when debugging (on an actual iPhone and Android device), I never see the bluetooth profile in the networkProfiles list, regardless of whether bluetooth is on and not paired, on and paired, or off.

I am able to see the wifi profile when wifi is connected however.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Using Share of Xamarin essentials, we can send data via Bluetooth.